# Apply configuration to Traefik

Tags: kubernetes

I've setup Traefik as the ingress controller in my kubernetes cluster and after a bunch of tweaking and googling I've managed to access the dashboard, but I'm currently getting `no providers found.` in the dashboard.  I know that I need to add kubernetes as a provider and have found how to do so in the config file (`traefik.toml`), but traefik is running as a deployment in k8s:

How do I apply a traefik configuration file to the deployment?  I've been googling for an hour or two now trying to figure it out, but it just seems to be self-evident to everyone but me as I've found nothing on the subject.

Comment: Hi, can You provide me with cluster environment information, kubernetes version and network plugin?

Comment: @jt97 The cluster is running in Azure AKS under Rancher.  We're using K8s v1.14.6, and I'm not sure what you mean by network plugin--I've been trying to use Traefik v1.7.